# Get Latitude and Longitude from result of google map v3 direction api?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I'm using `Google map v3 direction api` in my project.

I give cities name as a `start point` and `end point` for getting Distance and Time Taken for that distance.

I have another requirement to get longitude and latitude of start point which is city name.

Can I get it from direction api which is used by me to get distance and time taken in result of direction api?

If we can get latitude and longitude from  result of direction api, then please help me by giving proper answer.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The response does not contain a lat/lng string. You have to get it using a function.

Using jquery this works for me.

```
$.each(result.routes[0].legs, function(index, route) {
alert(route.start_location.lat());
});
```

This will alert each starting latitude for each leg of the journey you requested.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at the [responses section of the directions API documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsResponses) , it looks like you can get the start_location -> lat and start_location -> lng the same way you are already getting the distance and time.

I guess that would be:

```
routes.legs[0].start_location.lat
routes.legs[0].start_location.lng
```

Comment: Output from your code is :- function () {
    return this[a];
}

Comment: How about you put the code you're using to get the distance and time in your question? Then it would be easier to answer correctly.

Comment: alert(route.legs[0].start_location.lat.value);

Comment: above is your code which is I trid both way!!!!!!! with value without value.. with value it give me "undefined".....and without I said you earliar.

Comment: It should definitely be without `value`. I got route**s** (with s at the end), you got route instead. Myba that's the problem? Try `route.legs[0].start_location.lat`

Comment: Hello!!! it's only object name that will change by me.. it's not a thing which will effect code....Can you get lat and long value... in your environment!!!!

Comment: Yeah, I can. Did you have a look at the actual response text you get from the API? Are the lat and lng values in there?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4290/discussion-between-sikender-and-henningj)